# JQuery Checkbox Filtering

Tags: jquery, filtering

I have come in to an issue making a filtering system that adds a class to dampen the opacity of an element that doesn't match the checkbox criteria. When I try to reverse the process, to remove the class, either by using 'toggle' rather than 'click', or making a loop to test conditions, I run in to an error of the checkbox not working (no tick appears).

What I want to do, is that after the checkbox has been :unchecked, to remove the 'opacity' class, so that it returns to the initial, pre-filtered, page view. This is the code I have that causes no error, up until the removing of the opacity class:

```
$(".filters :checkbox").click(function(){
   $('.video-placeholder').addClass('opacity');
   $('.filters :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
       $("." + $(this).val()).addClass('opacity-full');
   });
});
```

Any help would be well received! I have hosted it here to see: http://yaocho-digital.com/83london/ - Thanks.

JP

Answer (score 0):

Below you'll find a jsFiddle of a basic representation of your code,

http://jsfiddle.net/zcQnj/27/

```
    $('.filters :checkbox:checked').each(function() {
        $("." + $(this).val()).removeClass('opacity').addClass('opacity-full');
    });

    if ( $('.filters :checkbox:checked').length == 0 ) 
        $('.video-placeholder').removeClass('opacity');
```

By removing opacity class at both when matched and when no filters have been applied, I hope I understood your question correctly!

Comment: Thanks! That works fine in the fiddle, yet when I add it to the site it goes a little weird. I think it may be due to the plugin that is replacing the checkboxes with images. Will have to have a further look.

Comment: You're welcome! If you need any more help, for example the checkbox/images replacing - just ask or alter your question :)